# Calculate $E[(F^{-1}(U)-G^{-1}(U))^2]$, where $F^{-1}(t)=\inf\{x\in\Bbb{R}|F(x)>t\}$.

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution

Let $F$ and $G$ be the cumulative functions of $N(\mu_1,\sigma_1^2)$ and $N(\mu_2,\sigma_2^2)$. Let $U$ be a uniformly distributed random variable on $[0,1]$. How to calculate $E[(F^{-1}(U)-G^{-1}(U))^2]$, where $F^{-1}(t)=\inf\{x\in\Bbb{R}|F(x)>t\}$?

For standard normal random variables, $F^{-1}$ is named as probit function, but I cannot find a direct expression to calculate the expectation as an integration.

Comment: If $F$ is a CDF of a continuous random variable, $U$ is a uniformly distributed random variable on $[0, 1]$, then the CDF of $F^{-1}(U)$ is exactly the same as $F$ - this is known as the inverse probability integral transform: $\Pr\{F^{-1}(U) \leq x\} = \Pr\{U \leq F(x)\} = F(x)$. So the distribution of both random variable are known. Next problem is that since both have the "same sources of randomness", you may express them in terms of the same random variable $Z$, say a standard normal one.

Comment: Sangchul Lee has already given the procedure for computing this in his comment on your previous post. Explicit computation in terms of $\mu_i, \sigma _i$ , $i=1,2$ may not be possible.